# Get an element inside an other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to access an `input` inside a specific `div`. I have this html :

```
<div id="'.str_replace(' ','',$systeme_culture['nom_plante']).'">
       <table class="table">
            <th>
                <tr colspan="2">
                      <label>Nom : </label>
                      <input id="nom_itk" value="test">
                </tr>
            </th>
       </table>
 </div>'
```

I want to access the id `nom_itk` inside the global div but I don't know how to do. I tried with `.find()` but it doesn't work.

My js is :

```
$('#'+nom_culture).find('#nom_itk').html("test");
```

The global div is called with the variable `nom_culture` in js.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: why not just `$('#nom_itk').html("test");` ???

Comment: What is the value of `nom_culture` variable ? Is it same as `str_replace(' ','',$systeme_culture['nom_plante'])` ?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The label and input are moved outside the table.

Comment: @PranavCBalan Because I will have several html code like that (dynamically generated), and I want it inside this specific div

Comment: `id` should be unique , so it will only work with first instance

Comment: IDs must be unique! Avoid "several html code like that"

Comment: @PranavCBalan There is only on column for the first row, so I don't need any `td`

Comment: child of `tr` should be `th` or `td`

Comment: @PranavCBalan This is not my question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code it's that you are using `html()` instead on `val()`

```
 $('#'+nom_culture).find('#nom_itk').val("test");
```

To your question you can also use

```
 $('#'+nom_culture + " #nom_itk").val("test");
```

(a space between the two) to select elements inside other elements

Comment: The `.html()` is just for the test, to know if I can access the right element. But this code doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to access an input element, which has no content (so you can't change it with `.html()`), but a value.

Assuming the `nom_culture` variable finds the right element (a parent of `#nom_itk`), this will do what you want:

```
$('#'+nom_culture).find('#nom_itk').val('test');
```

Comment: Thanks but the `.html()` is here just for check if I can access th right element, and I can't.

Comment: In that case please edit your question to state your actual work model, or specify your question. find() is the correct solution for what you're trying to do - but as long as you're testing it with html(), you won't see any results.

Answer (score 0):

Below script will give you nom_itk value test

```
 $('#'+nom_culture).find('#nom_itk').val();
```

and below will provide you object array

```
 $('#'+nom_culture).find('#nom_itk').val('test');
 $('#'+nom_culture).find('#nom_itk').html('test');
```